# Videos uploaded through YouTube API v3 are uploaded with Community Contributions OFF

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have "Community contributions" enabled (turned on) for my YouTube account. This should turn on contributions for newly uploaded videos. If I uploaded video manually through the Video manager, checkbox on Community contribution is ON for this newly created video. However, if I upload video using API v3 (from samples) or even via iMovie - checkbox is OFF.

Is there a way to upload a video through API v3 and have Community contribution checkbox automatically be set into ON state?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported by the API yet.

[image: This is only done] using the [manual operation](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6052538?hl=en) as of now. You're only able to do this after videos have been uploaded not while uploading videos.